SQL Server Agent Alert to Detect deadlocks
Some SQL Server Agent jobs failed recently with deadlock errors. I wanted to keep an eye on the issue and created a monitoring alert in SSMS. However, the event never fires.. which seems wrong.
Alert Properties:

Alert scripted:
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'Deadlock(s) detected . . .', 
    @message_id=0, 
    @severity=0, 
    @enabled=1, 
    @delay_between_responses=720, 
    @include_event_description_in=1, 
    @category_name=N'[Uncategorized]', 
    @performance_condition=N'Locks|Number of Deadlocks/sec|Database|>|0', 
    @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_notification @alert_name=N'Deadlock(s) detected . . .', 
    @operator_name=N'Watchdog', @notification_method = 1

What's missing? Or is there a better way to do this?

Do you know for sure that the alert never fires, or is it maybe just that the notification is not finding its way to where it should?  Do you know, for sure, that notifications to the "Watchdog" operator work successfully?

Yes, I do because there is a History panel on the Alert Properties dialog that shows: Date of last alert: (Never occurred). Number of occurrences: 0.

The error has to be written to the event log, which is what agent is polling. 1205 is by default not written to the event log (or errorlog). You can change this using sp_altermessage.

Nice. Thank you for pointing me in the right direct!
